# nhibernate table per class hierarchy, mapping derived class members which hide base class members

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

```
class FooBase{...}
class FooDerived : FooBase {...}

class BaseContainer
{
    public virtual FooBase Foo {get;set;}
}

class DerivedContainer : BaseContainer
{
    public virtual new FooDerived Foo {get;set;}
}
```

Hibernate mapping options
Option 1 below
Fails to persist on a/c of NHibernate generating additional member declaration in the xml (index out of range error)

```
   <class name="BaseContainer" discriminator-value="0">

         <discriminator column="ContainerType" type="int" />

         <many-to-one name="Foo"
                      foreign-key="..."
                      class="FooBase"
                      column="FooId"
                      unique="true"/>

          <subclass name="DerivedContainer"  discriminator-value="1">

               <many-to-one name="Foo"
                            foreign-key="..."
                            class="FooDerived"
                            column="FooId"

                            unique="true"/>
          </subclass>

   </class>
```

Option 2 independent mappings !
Fetch operation erroneous, does not discriminate the types

```
   <class name="BaseContainer" discriminator-value="0">

         <discriminator column="ContainerType" type="int" />

         <many-to-one name="Foo"
                      foreign-key="..."
                      class="FooBase"
                      column="FooId"
                      unique="true"/>

   </class>

   <class name="DerivedContainer"  discriminator-value="1">

        <many-to-one name="Foo"
                     foreign-key="..."
                     class="FooDerived"
                     column="FooId"
                     unique="true"/>

  </class>
```

Stuck, would be grateful for any pointers, although I understand this can easily achieved if done via table per subclass, is there any way above can be achieved via table per class hierarchy